# RPM spec use prefix in post

Tags: rpm

I have some files (RPMs) which I want to pack into one RPM and make them available somewhere else as a repository.

A requirement for this RPM is to make it relocatable.
`rpm -Uvh --prefix ...`

The relocation by its self was no problem and works as expected.
In my %post (important part marked with #) of the spec file where I want to preconfigure the outcome repository, the prefix parameter won't change when I call it like:
`rpm -Uvh --prefix /some/other/path some_rpm_name-some_rpm_version`.

I tried a lot of things but won't change like:

```
Prefix: /mnt/extern
%global SOME_VAR %{prefix}
```

```
Prefix: /mnt/extern
%global REPO_NAME somerepo

Name:           some_rpm_name
Version:        some_rpm_version
Release:        1%{?dist}

Source:         yum.tar.gz

%prep
%setup -n yum

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{prefix}
cp -r %{_builddir}/yum %{buildroot}%{prefix}

%files
%{prefix}/yum

%post
echo '[%{REPO_NAME}]' | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/%{CABIS_REPO_FILE}.repo 
echo 'name = %{REPO_NAME}' | sudo tee -a  /etc/yum.repos.d/%{CABIS_REPO_FILE}.repo 
########################
echo 'baseurl = file://%{prefix}/yum/' | sudo tee -a  /etc/yum.repos.d/%{CABIS_REPO_FILE}.repo 
########################
echo 'gpgcheck = 0' | sudo tee -a  /etc/yum.repos.d/%{CABIS_REPO_FILE}.repo 
echo 'enabled = 1' | sudo tee -a  /etc/yum.repos.d/%{CABIS_REPO_FILE}.repo
```

Expecting result:

```
[somerepo]
name = somerepo
baseurl = file:///some/other/path/yum/
gpgcheck = 0
enabled = 1
```

Actual result:

```
[somerepo]
name = somerepo
baseurl = file:///mnt/extern/yum/
gpgcheck = 0
enabled = 1
```

But the files are relocated to `/some/other/path`.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation:
  http://ftp.rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/relocatable.html

the format of calling rpm is:

```
rpm -Uvh --prefix /mnt/extern=/some/other/path some_rpm_name-some_rpm_version.
```

Comment: Neither `--prefix` nor `--relocate` do the job.
And according to [rpm manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm) 
`--prefix NEWPATH)` and `--relocate OLDPATH=NEWPATH` do the same thing except with the second one you can change multiple Prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the variables you want to use are `$RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX0`, `$RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX1`, etc. See [this example](https://github.com/opencpi/opencpi/blob/master/packaging/cdk.spec).

Honestly, I've never been a fan of relocatable RPMs because you're still limited to one installed per RPM DB and they're obnoxiously finicky.